# Forecasting formula in mathematical notation help please:

Tags: self-study, forecasting, prediction, notation

Question: is what I have correct? If not what is correct?

I am not sure how to correctly write this forecasting model in proper mathematical notation. My attempt is at the bottom, please help fix or change my mistakes.

Model Information:
This is a forecasting model that is being used to predict the open value of stocks and crypto currencies.

This model is loosely based on the X-11 model (this is a simpler version due to time constraints to create):
https://www.census.gov/ts/papers/Conference1983/Wallis1983.pdf

This model was chosen because it takes into account seasonality for the prediction and then I added an additional smoothing ratio based on testing observations. If there was a high error, it was reduced by adding in the smoothing ratio.

Reason for question/request of help:
I'm working on a masters thesis and would like to provide an accurate mathematical representation of the model that i built. My attempt is below but i am not sure if it is correct and would like assistance regarding the mathematical notation structure. (ex: am i using the correct sub/hyper scripts?)

Background and Formula:
To create the forecasting model, an average of the previous 7 days exchange rates are taken from the current year and again from the previous year. The previous year is to create a basis of what is to be expected in the future and the current year average is used to capture the increase or decrease over time. 
Current = average of previous seven days in current year
Previous = average of previous seven days in previous year

The ratio of the current average over the previous average is used to create a prediction ratio. For the prediction, based on the forecasting date,  the exchange rate of the previous year is multiplied by the the ratio to create an initial prediction. There was also a smoothing event added that takes a ratio of the current prediction ratio over the previous ratio and multiplies the prediction to reduce error.

Some variables:

n: number of days in prediction range

d: date

My Formula:

$$ {P\left(d\right)}_i\ \ =open\ price\ of\ date\\
\mu_c=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=d-n-1}^{d-1}{{P\left(d\right)}_i\ \ \ current\ year\ average} \\
\mu_p=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=d-n-366}^{d-366}{P\left(d\right)}_i\ \ previous\ year\ average\\  
R\ =\mu_c/\mu_p\ \ \ seasonality\ ratio\\ 
{I(d)}_0\ \ =R(d)/P(d-365)\ initial\ prediction\\
 {S\ =\ I(d)}_0/{I(d-1)}_0\ \ \ smoothing\ ratio\\ 
{I\left(d\right)}_1=S\ast I\left(d\right)_0 \ \ \ Smoothed\ prediction $$

Comment: Hi there and welcome. As a rule on this site: please do not post pictures of formulas; instead write them out in math mode: e.g. `$ I(d)_1 = S^* I(d)_0 $` becomes $I(d)_1=S^* I(d)_0$. Thank you. – *Reviewer*

Comment: In addition, please add the `self-study` tag and read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I cannot find a question in this post--what are you trying to ask?

Comment: question is this correct and if not how should it be?

Comment: If you keep reposting this question, the site will automatically prevent you from posting anything more.  *Please* just edit this question to clarify it.  The community members will then be able to take it off hold.

Comment: @whuber I tried to make a new one and delete this one because it is still on hold after i updated the question a few time.

Comment: You have to wait for the community to vote to reopen it: merely changing it is not sufficient.  These things are explained in our [help], which you might like to read so that you can make the most of this site.

Comment: @whuber I don't suppose you would consider up voting me? I made the corrections to the question and formula using latex. I really need this for a project i'm working on.please :)

Comment: @Jim I fixed the requested changes and was hoping you could vote for me so i can be taken off hold? please :) Im working on a project and would greatly appreciate getting this settled :)

Comment: @JenniferJarnstrom You're almost there. Please keep in mind that even though you "need" an answer "now", this site is not here for that purpose. It aims to be a repository of well-posed questions and great answers useful to as many people as possible. To get your question into that form: 1) What is this model's name? Provide a hyperlink to a relevant source, e.g. Wikipedia. 2) Why is that model appropriate for your problem? 3) Then your question would/could be if the way you wrote things down is consistent with that model (and its assumptions) and if it's suitable for your problem. Best

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your guidance, i am new to this site. I have added the information that you mentioned in hopes of getting closer to my answer. Thank you.